# ActionCodeSettings not updated in the link sent by email

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to modify the parameters of the actionCodeSettings, the url to be exact and it doesn't get updated. When i open the link from the email sent, is redirects to the old url that i updated. Is it the api that need times to register or am I doing something wrong?

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
  url: "http://tryingToChangeThis.com/signup/register",
  handleCodeInApp: true,
};
firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(req.body.email, actionCodeSettings)
.then(()=>{
  console.log('ok');
  res.status(HttpStatus.OK).end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation always redirects to the email action URL configured in the Auth > email template section in the Firebase Console which will then redirect to the url in the `ActionCodeSettings` with the parameters appended. This is the behavior of the default page provided by Firebase Auth.

If you want to update the original email domain (email action URL), you can directly modify in the Firebase Console.